# Как передать параметр в factory на laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

Есть необходимость засеять БД данными на разных языках. Например, модель `Books` с полями `title`, `content` и указанием на язык из другой таблицы - `language_id`

```
Schema::create('languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('code', 2);
    $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('language_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('content');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('language_id')->references('id')->on('languages')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Создаю `BookFactory`

```
class BookFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => fake()->sentence(rand(3, 7)),
            'content' => fake()->sentences(rand(5, 11))
        ];
    }
}
```

функция fake() может принимать параметр, указывающий на [язык](https://fakerphp.github.io/locales/ru_RU/), на котором следует генерировать данные, например, `de_DE` или `ru_RU`.

Как мне передать в facotry переменную с указанием локали из сидера?

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {   
        \App\Models\Book::factory(10)->create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё делается довольно просто. Определите в Вашей фабрике дополнительный метод, который будет принимать параметр языка. Он должен возвращать результат вызова `$this->state(...)`. Пример.

```
public function withLang(string $lang)
{
    return $this->state(function (array $attributes) use ($lang) {
        return [
            'name' => fake($lang)->name,
            'lastName' => fake($lang)->lastName,
        ];
    });
}

\App\Models\User::factory()->count(5)->withLang('de_DE')->create();
\App\Models\User::factory()->count(7)->withLang('ru_RU')->create();
```